# RegExp Replace non matching character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have word

"Hello This is world This"

Code

```
 var patt = 'Hello This is world This'
    var res = patt.constructor;
alert(patt.replace(new RegExp('('This')', 'gi'), "<b>$1</b>"));
```

I tried with some combination but not working.

basically I have to bold the words other than This.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: I don't have to bold This, other than This

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead.

```
var patt = 'Hello This is world This'
patt.replace(/\b(?!this\b)(\w+)\b/gi, "<b>$1</b>")
# '<b>Hello</b> This <b>is</b> <b>world</b> This'
```

Using `RegExp`

```
> patt.replace(new RegExp("\\b(?!this\\b)(\\w+)\\b", "gi"), "<b>$1</b>")
'<b>Hello</b> This <b>is</b> <b>world</b> This'
```

Comment: Thanks it is working , but What if I have to do this for multiple word, like This is, I think this \\w+ breaking the space

Comment: just add the words inside the lookahead like, `patt.replace(/\b(?!(?:is|this)\b)(\w+)\b/gi, "<b>$1</b>")`

Comment: then i think it will find either is or this, I have to find exactly a substring whatever in a variable say look='This is'